# Firebase Auth & Google MlKit Face detection

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, google-mlkit

I have a flutter project that use a firebase auth for login and registration, and i want to add google_mlkit_face_detection to detect face on an image, but the google_mlkit_face_detection and firebase_auth conflict each other for IOS, when runing pod install show me this error.

```
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
```

To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

this is the hole error

> CocoaPods' output:
> ↳
> Preparing
> Analyzing dependencies
> Inspecting targets to integrate
> Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
> Finding Podfile changes
> A google_mlkit_commons
> A google_mlkit_face_detection
> - Flutter
> - firebase_auth
> - firebase_core
> - image_picker_ios
> - path_provider_foundation
> Fetching external sources
> -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
> -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
> firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
> firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `google_mlkit_commons` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_commons/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `google_mlkit_face_detection` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
> CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/1/e/MLKitVision/5.0.0/MLKitVision.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_e_b.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> 2
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/e/b/GoogleMLKit/4.0.0/GoogleMLKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/10.10.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

- 

```
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, = 3.1.1, >= 2.1)
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.6.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.9.0) was resolved to 10.9.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 10.9.0) was resolved to 10.9.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)
    google_mlkit_face_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.7.0, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
        GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
          MLKitCommon (~> 9.0.0) was resolved to 9.0.0, which depends on
            GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.1)
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `GTMSessionFetcher/Core` inside your development pod `google_mlkit_face_detection`.
   You should run `pod update GTMSessionFetcher/Core` to apply changes you've made.
```

and pubspec.yamel file

> dependencies:

```
flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  firebase_core: any
  firebase_auth: any
  #google_mlkit_commons: ^0.4.0
  google_mlkit_face_detection: any
  

  get: ^4.6.5
  get_storage: ^2.1.1
  dio: ^5.1.2

  image_picker: ^0.8.7

  iconly: ^1.0.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
  age_calculator: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `pod deintegrate; pod update`

FirebaseAuth and MLKit are compatible. `< 4.0, >= 2.1` is compatible with `< 3.0, >= 1.1` if a 2.x version of GTMSessionFetcher is installed.

The problem is that 3.1.1 is already installed. It needs to be deleted and then the pods reinstalled.